# PHP using OR but avoid running when both cases are true

Tags: php

I am running into a problem.

I am using a recursive function that will pass the case to run to another function.

The problem is that I am doing the following:

```
if ($case == 1 || count($matching) == 0 && $case == NULL)
    do something....
```

So 'do something' only if the `$case == 1` OR only if `$matching > 0` and `$case == NULL`

Looks like that PHP does not correctly understand it.

In fact if `$case == 1` and `$matching > 0` it will run anyway the 'do something' even if it should not, because I said to it to run 'do something' when `$matching > 0` only if `$case` is `also == NULL`.

What's wrong?

How do I tell to PHP to run only if `$case == 1` OR ONLY if `$matching > 0` AND also `$case == NULL` ?

Comment: Use `XOR` and learn operators precedence.

Comment: In mathematical logic and, `or` means `at least one` of the cases has to be true, not exactly one, for the entire statement to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [XOR logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (XOR comes from eXclusive OR):

```
if ($case == 1 xor ($matching > 0 && $case == null)) { ... }
```

Comment: If $case is a boolean, then couldn't you just use `if($case == 1 xor $matching > 0)`

Comment: Also, typo: $case1 should be $case

Comment: @Kian No, for the case in which $case == 1, $matching > 0, the block should not execute but for that expression it would

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, && takes precedent over ||, so you need to add brackets:

```
($case == 1 || (count($matching) == 0 && $case == NULL) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will ensure that last 2 conditions are grouped together and the result of those 2 is true if and only if both of them are true:

```
if ($case == 1 || (count($matching) > 0 && $case == NULL)){
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment to explain `why` to make the proposed changes, thanks!

Comment: Added a brief explanation. Hope that helps the OP. Please feel free to suggest any other improvements to the explanation.